# Changing working directory in Scala

Tags: scala

I am working with Scala in Eclipse IDE on a Windows machine.

I am trying to get a list of files from a specific directory:

```
    val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles
```

This provides the file names of all the files in the default directory which is D:\Scala\eclipse. This is confirmed by the following command:

```
    System.getProperty("user.dir")                  
    > res23: String = D:\Scala\eclipse
```

I tried changing the directory to a different location with the following command (Based on suggestions from [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5164.html))

```
    System.setProperty("user.dir","D:/Scala/")
```

Looks like the user directory is changed as confirmed by the following command:

```
    System.getProperty("user.dir")                  
    > res25: String = D:/Scala/
```

However, the following command list the files from the default directory and not the new directory:

```
    val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles
```

Could someone explain how to make it point to the new directory?

Comment: Try `new java.io.File("D:/Scala/").listFiles`

Comment: Thanks, this works great. However, this lists the files along with the complete path...is there a way to get only the name of the file without the complete path?

Comment: It returns new `File` objects actually, get the file name without path with `getName`.

Comment: I tried this val fileList = (new java.io.File("D:/Scala/")).getName  but this only returns fileList  : String = Scala and doesn't return all the file names

Comment: No, do `new java.io.File("D:/Scala/").listFiles.map(_.getName)`